# Email alert when a cell value equals or is less than a number in PHP/mySQL. Possible?

Tags: mysql

I have a mySQl.  I have an inventory database.  I would like to send an email to a person when the inventory is equal or less than a preset value.

Is this possible on client side or server side? using PHP?

Any examples?

Erik

Comment: You can use triggers to monitor for certain conditions, but MySQL has no email capabilities built in. You'd need an extension/plugin for that ,or an external monitoring script.

Comment: I'd create a cron script (in PHP or something else) to poll the inventory every few minutes and kick out an email when you fall beneath your threshold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test via cron (or a scheduled task), setup a script like this to run every few minutes.  If you wanted to be clever, store the notification threshold in the database along with the product.  That would enable you to notify multiple people for multiple products in a loop.

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
// Your preset inventory...
$threshold = 5;
$recipient = "email@example.com";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT inventory FROM tbl WHERE product='whatever';");
if ($result) {
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  $inventory = $row['inventory'];
  if ($inventory <= $threshold) {
    $msg = "Inventory for product has fallen beneath threshold. $inventory remaining.";
    mail($recipient, "Inventory check below threshold", $msg);
  }
}
else {
  $msg = "An error occurred while checking inventory: " . mysql_error();
  mail($recipient, "Inventory check error", $msg);
}
?>
```

To run this every ten minutes via cron:

```
 */10 * * * * /path/to/this/script.php
```

Answer (score 0):

If your server is set up for it, you can use the [`mail` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

Comment: I'd like to post a more detailed answer, but I'm really not sure what you're trying to do. Can you expand on your process a little bit more?

Answer (score 0):

PHP runs on server side, this answer your first question. Then you need to know if php mail function can be used in your hosting server or you need to use some php library like [swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/)

I don't know what your database structure looks like but simply select all email field from all users where invertory is equal or less than a preset value.

Finally iterate through each result and send the mail using the functions I mentioned above.

I suggest to add database info in your question because it's difficult to help this way.